# Expected number of players to have pocket aces

Tags: probability, expected-value, card-games

There are 6 people, each dealt 2 cards from a standard deck. What is the expected number of players that have two aces?

> My approach to this was multiplying probability of 1 player gets 2 aces with 1 and added that with probability that 2 players gets two aces and multiplying that by two. Is this the best way to solve or is there a more clever approach?

Comment: Linearity is somewhat easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be an indicator variable that is equal to $1$ if  person $i$ gets $2$ aces, and $0$ otherwise, then

$P(X_i) = \Large\frac{\binom42}{\binom{52}2}=\frac1{221}$

The expectation of an indicator variable is just the probability of the event it indicates, thus

$\Bbb E[X_i] = \Large\frac1{221},$

and by linearity of expectation, which applies even when the variables ar not independent,

$\Bbb E[X] = \Sigma \Bbb E[Xi] = \Large\frac{6}{221}$

Comment: How can the probability for each person be the same? Answer seems to suggest that each 2 cards dealt are replaced.

Comment: @sle: No, it is without replacement. Imagine that $12$ top cards from a shuffled deck are laid out in a line. Aces asre equally likely to be in the first four cards as, say,  the last four cards.